# Counting the number of visible rows after autofilter

Tags: excel, vba

How do you count the number of visible/not null rows (from row 3 onwards, checking if column A is empty) after an autofilter? Right now I am only getting 26...

Full code:

```
Sub GetPrimaryContacts()

Dim Col As New Collection
Dim itm
Dim i As Long
Dim CellVell As Variant

'Get last row value
LastRow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

'Loop between all rows to get unique values
For i = 3 To LastRow
    CellVal = Sheets("Master").Range("F" & i).Value
    On Error Resume Next
    Col.Add CellVal, Chr(34) & CellVal & Chr(34)
    On Error GoTo 0
Next i

' Create workbooks - Token Not activated
Call TokenNotActivated
For Each itm In Col
    ActiveSheet.Range("A2:Z2").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=itm
    Call CountFilterAreaRows
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: If Row 3 is hidden, it doesn't have any Visible cells... Perhaps you are trying to get the first visible row?

Comment: See update to the question I managed to do some debugging but at the moment lcount is not updating after the first error

Comment: Criteria1:=itm should be after row 3. Because when you filter the value if it does not exit then error occurred. And also set the range for col.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function that will count the visible rows in an autofiltered range, even if there are none:

```
Function CountFilterAreaRows(ws As Excel.Worksheet) As Long
Dim FilterArea As Excel.Range
Dim RowsCount As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet
For Each FilterArea In ws.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    RowsCount = RowsCount + FilterArea.Rows.Count
Next FilterArea
'don't count the header
RowsCount = RowsCount - 1
CountFilterAreaRows = RowsCount
End Function
```

To call it as a function, see the edits above. Using your example you would could call it something like this (Untested):

```
Sub UseIt()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim itm
Dim col As Collection

'... your col logic

For Each itm In col
Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Range("A2:Z2").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=itm
    Debug.Print CountFilterAreaRows(ws)
Next itm
End Sub
```

Note that you should [avoid the use of `Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/293078).

Comment: Thanks - how would I call it from my function (I've updated the question)?

Comment: I get an "expected end function" error message when running it (happening in the CountFilterAreaRows function at EndSub)

Comment: Woops, I just edited the function (on my phone). Hopefully it works now.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, because I am guessing at what your code is actually doing, but see if this gets what you want done.

```
For Each itm In Col
    RowCount = Sheets("Master").Rows(itm.Row).Count
    MsgBox RowCount 
Next
```

Comment: OK I thought Col was a column, not Collection.

Answer (score 1):

Say we have an AutoFilter with the first row containing headers and nothing below the filtered table:

```
Sub visiCount()
    Dim r As Range, n as Long
    n = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set r = Range("A1:A" & n).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    MsgBox r.Count - 1
End Sub
```

**EDIT** ............started at **A1** rather than **A2**

Comment: I get an overflow error message when there no rows to count

Answer (score 0):

@doug
I found your code and it looked promising to me. Unfortunately, the results did not match the numbers in the Excel status bar at all (Excel 2019). As I found out, the function counted individual cells of the filter range, and not - as probably intended - the number of rows of the individual filter areas.

I also fixed the bug with the worksheet variable; instead of taking the function parameter, your code always set the worksheet variable to ActiveSheet.

The working code now looks like this, and returns exactly the numbers that Excel also shows in the status bar:

```
Function CountFilterAreaRows(Optional ByVal Ws As Excel.Worksheet) As Long

    Dim FilterArea As Excel.Range, FilterRange As Excel.Range
    Dim RowsCount As Long
    
    If Ws Is Nothing Then Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    Set FilterRange = Ws.AutoFilter.Range
    Set FilterRange = FilterRange.Offset(1).Resize(FilterRange.Rows.Count - 1) ' skip header row
    
    For Each FilterArea In FilterRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas ' without ".Areas" the function was countig every single cell
        RowsCount = RowsCount + FilterArea.Rows.Count
    Next FilterArea
    
    CountFilterAreaRows = RowsCount
End Function
```